# What should the subject of the next three months blog-posts be?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

I am finishing up a [schedule](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FqdpiJSEy5gUq455Pjp6ge-lTwb3ykLgKN6fH7yOH-U/edit?usp=sharing) for the next three months, and for now I would like to work on what subjects the blog-posts will be on in each of these months.  We can sort out who will write them later, for now What suggestions do you have for a topic?  The suggestions most upvoted shall be chosen and filled into the schedule, furthermore the subject can be about Da'wah, a surat of the Quran or something else, what is your suggestion?

***Edit: The schedule has been completed.***

Answer (score 3):

[Eid al-adha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Adha)  is coming soon. It might be a good topic.

**Note:** I am writing my suggestions in separate posts in order to allow separate voting.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a blog post be written describing/explaining/naming various names of location that occur in Quran and Hadith with their modern names. Like Damascus, Lebnanon, Palestine are mentioned at various places but these are the english names which people know. I myself and I guess many others find the names confusing when they come across various hadith for example the one relating the signs of Last Hour.

This does require someone with the proper knowledge and research. I myself try to find and investigate the name of places, but still find it difficult.

Such a blog post will really be helpful in better understanding of many things.

Comment: This could actually be very interesting if done as a series, with each post focussing on one such location and it's historic context in Islam.

Comment: Agree. A series is required as one blog can't focus on all locations in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu aleikum.

I feel there has been an overload over the years on sundry topics about Islam like, for instance, aqeedah, duties of a Muslim, dawah, et al. People can find plenty of sites which give information about these aspects of Islam. I think we need to refresh our focus on more contemporary topics, topics that are of interest to folks out there who need to know Islam's perspectives about some of the contemporary issues facing the Ummah today and the world at large.

What are these issues? I can think of at least two as examples.

1. Vaccinations: We need to have a more balanced view on this. Our ulema need to rope in the help of qualified professionals from *both sides* of the debate about whether vaccinations are necessary or not; whether they are halaal or haraam based on their ingredients; and most importantly, do they harm our children or are they just benign instruments of altruism for humanity, as the mainstream line of thought make them out to be. While this may surprise many as something that cannot and should not be questioned, this issue needs to be addressed from a non-partisan and non-dogmatic perspective.
2. GMOs: Genetically Modified Organisms or GMO foods and crops are being opposed everywhere, throughout the world. Entire countries have already banned or are banning GMOs. What are our Ulema doing about this?

Unfortunately for us and Muslims the world over, our scholars have kept mum on these extremely critical issues, either out of lack of knowledge, or maybe because the powers-that-be support the wrong side of these issues; or perhaps it is simply politically incorrect to speak against them.

It would be very beneficial for the Muslims that these very crucial issues be addressed. We can at least kick off the process.

Comment: the above topics are already controversial, how can a blog post help in this except to show a partisan view, anyways these are novel topics and should be encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Subject: One year of islam stackexchange.

It has been over one year since islam stackexhange have been launched. Maybe someone can summarize what we have been doing in this time span.