# The complete 2014 Blog-Post series schedule

Tags: discussion, community-blog

This years blog posts is based on this suggestion [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/831/9) along with the [comment](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/819/what-should-the-subject-of-the-next-three-months-blog-posts-be#comment1560_831) under it.  [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v7d3UupthKil3RIHAkEzQI0ZNHCYPQHesKCnYb9qTOo/edit) is the schedule for the series.  The name of the series overall is "The Story of this land" It will be talking about some of the lands in the Quran, mentioning some of it's history before the time of Muhammad ﷺ  and it history after him ﷺ, it will also mention the excellence narrated in regards to some of these lands.  There are five **main** parts to this series, the first is on Palestine, the second on Iraq, the third on Egypt, the fourth on Al Yaman, and the fifth is a wrap up for the series.

Each part except for the last, is split into sub-parts/posts, the first part is split into six parts/posts, the second is split into four parts/posts, the third and fourth parts are each split into two parts/posts.  Each post is scheduled for a certain already determined date, the series officially started on January 30th and will end on July 15.  My intention in writing this meta post is to find contributors who are willing to author one or more blog-post in the schedule.

If you are willing and able to author one or more posts, then please look at the schedule below, find the post you want to write which does not have an "Author:" filled in, and give an answer under this meta post or come to our [blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8205/islam-ses-blog-chatroom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Schedule**

**Wednesday, January 15, 2014**

Subject: Biladu Shaam (بلاد الشام)

Description:  Short post talking about the excellence of Shaam and mentioning the authentic Ahadeeth in regards to it.  This blog post would not be a part of the series, but would serve as an introduction to the first few parts/posts of the series.

Author: Al Ummat

**Thursday, January 30, 2014**

Subject: Filisteen (فلسطين) / Palestine

Title: Story of this Land Part 1: The blessed/holy land Pt1

Description: This post will talk about the richness of history of Palestine/ فلسطين ,  as well as it’s excellence and  importance.  It will mention the Ayat in the Quran about it, along with some of the authentic Ahadeeth in regards to it.

Author: Al Ummat

**Saturday, February 15, 2014**

Subject: Filisteen (فلسطين) / Palestine

Title: The Blessed Land Part 2: Bani Isra’eel

Description: Talking about the history of Bani Isra’eel and Palestine/ فلسطين  , from after the 40 years, until their first falling. Then starting back up from 1948 to present day.

Author: Al Ummat

**Saturday, March 1, 2014**

Subject: Filisteen (فلسطين) / Palestine, The Futuhaat / الفتوحات

Title: The Blessed Land Part 3: The rightly guided Khulafa’

Description: History of the beginning of the conquests of Shaam which includes Palestine on the hands of Abu Bakr, and the completion on the hands of Umar.

Author: Muz

**Saturday, March 15, 2014**

Subject: Filisteen (فلسطين) / Palestine, The crusades

Title: The Blessed Land Part 4: The Crusades

Author: Al Ummat

**Sunday, March 30, 2014**

Subject: Filisteen (فلسطين) / Palestine, The Mongols

Title: The Blessed Land Part 5: The Mongols

Author: Al Ummat

**Tuesday, April 15, 2014**

Subject: Filisteen (فلسطين) / Palestine, The British

Title: The Blessed Land Part 6: The British

Author: Al Ummat

**Friday, April 25, 2014**

Subject: Iraq, Quran

Title: Story of this Land Part 2: Iraq Pt 1: (This part of the title can be decided by the Author)

Description: Blog-post talking about the mention of Iraq in the Quran, with explanation of the Ayaat/verses.

Author: Al Ummat

***Series Break***

**Sunday, June 15, 2014**

Subject: Iraq, Hadith
Title: Iraq Part 2: (This part of the title can be decided by the Author)

Description: Blog-Post talking about what came in the Authentic Ahadeeth in regards to this land, and explanation of them.

Author:مجاهد

**Sunday, July 20, 2014**

Subject:  Iraq, Futuhaat, Abu Bakr

Title: Iraq Part 3: The beginning of the conquests of Iraq

Description:  Blog-Post talking about the decision of Abu Bakr (رضي الله عنه) on sending armies to fight the Roman and Persian empires, his plan for the armies sent to Iraq, and a summary of the accomplishments done up until his death.

Author:

**Tuesday, August 19,  2014**

Subject: Iraq, Futuhaat, Umar

Title: Iraq Part 4: The Time of Umar

Description: Blog-Post summarizing the main events and accomplishments in the conquests of Iraq and persia during the time of Umar (May Allah be pleased with him).

Author:

**Wednesday, September 17, 2014**

Subject: Egypt in the Quran

Title: Story of this Land Part 3: Egypt Part 1: (This part of the title can be decided by the Author) 
Description: Blog-Post talking about egypt in the Quran, and mentioning the Stories of Yusuf (Peace be upon him) and Musa and Bani Isra’il, along with the form of government of Egypt for instance during Yusuf time, and how it was during Musa time.  The post will also mention the story of Bani Isra’il in Egypt, how they came, what happened after the death of Yusuf, and the events before the birth of Musa.

Author:

**Thursday, October 16, 2014**

Subject: Egypt, Futuhaat

Title: Egypt Part 2: (This part of the title can be decided by the Author)

Description: Blog-Post talking about the conquest of Egypt, some background before it’s conquest, and history after it.

Author:

**Friday, November 14, 2014**

Subject: Al Yaman in the Quran and Sunnah

Title: Story of this Land Part 4: Al Yaman Part 1:  (This part of the title can be decided by the Author)

Description: Blog Post talking about the verses in which Al Yaman is mentioned, as well as Authentic Ahadeeth in regards to it and it’s Excellence, with explanation.

Author:

**Monday, December 1, 2014**

Al Yaman Part 2:  (This part of the title can be decided by the Author)

Description: Blog-Post talking about the importance and contributions of Al Yaman during the life of the Prophet (Peace and blessings be upon him) and after him.

Author:

**Tuesday, December 30, 2014**

Title: Story of this Land Part 5: Wrap Up

Description: Blog-Post summarizing what has been gone over through the series, as well as mentioning the importance of history, as well as some lands which have not been spoken about during the series.  This blog-post will also mention the modern state of some of these lands and what is happening in them.  This blog-post is the last of this series, and is intended to simply wrap up things.

Author: