# Should the schedule and topics of the blog post be self-contained in the question?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

I have noticed that the topics schedules of the blog post series are designed and maintain on a Google Doc. e.g. [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v7d3UupthKil3RIHAkEzQI0ZNHCYPQHesKCnYb9qTOo/edit) for [The complete 2014 Blog-Post series schedule](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/885/3487).

Should the schedule be self-contained within the post itself and not contained in on an external source?

Comment: I have been convinced that it should, I have edited the schedule into the meta post.

Comment: @AlUmmat Might as well post that into an answer, so it can be accepted.